# Replace element and on click return the old element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following function:

```
datum.on('change', function(){
    var url = '<?php echo base_url()  ?>admin/admin_tvprogram .tvprogram > *';
    tvprogram.empty().load(url, {'datum':$(this).val()}, function(){
        var izmeni = $(this).find('a');
        izmeni.on('click', function(){
            var sat = $(this).parent().find('.sat'),
            sat_vrednost = sat.text(),
            naziv = $(this).parent().find('.naziv'),
            naziv_vrednost = naziv.text(),
            vrati = $(this).parent().append('<span class=vrati>Vrati</span>');

            var novi_sat = sat.replaceWith('<input type=text name=sat value=' + sat_vrednost + ' >' ),
            novi_naziv = naziv.replaceWith('<input type=text name=naziv value=' + naziv_vrednost + ' >' );

        });
    });
});
```

Everything is working fine, but I need one more functionality. When a user click on **vrati** (new appended **span** element), elements **sat** and **naziv** need to return to original form. How can I do this?

When load function is activated I get following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <span class="sat">18:00</span>
    <span class="naziv">Opravka Traktora</span>
    <a data-id="2">Izmeni</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

After **izmeni** is clicked I get following HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
<input type="text" value="18:00" name="sat">
<input type="text" traktora="" value="Opravka" name="naziv">
<a data-id="2">Izmeni</a>
<span class="vrati">Vrati</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @MikeBrant I have updated HTML part of the code.

Comment: i think you'll find my answer short and simple

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the values of the elements right when the user clicks.

Probably need to save the values before doing the load and then the same code in the on-click will restore them.

Comment: There are multiple elements that can be clicked, with separate children containing different informations. When **izmeni** is clicked I need to grab information for his children. I guess this have some logic o.O

Answer (score 0):

Populate your list input tables from variables that you define, and then apply the j query .text action to your sat and naziv giving them the parameter of that variable again when vrati is clicked

//the function textvalueToggle gets called on document load assigning the values to sat and naziv. Then a click listener is attached to vrati to call that same function reassigning the values

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
           textvalueToggle();
           $('#vrati').click(textvalueToggle);
    });

    function textvalueToggle() {
       $('#sat').text('18:00');
       $('#naziv').text('Opravka Traktora');
   }
```